# Python3 redefine a class: super still calls old class

Tags: python-3.x, class, redefinition

This code:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        print("a here")

class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        print("b here")
        super().__init__()

B = b()

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        print("NEW a here")

BB = b()
```

produces this output:

```
b here
a here
b here
a here
```

Why?

If I change the super().**init**() in class b to a.**init**(self), it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `b` holds a reference to its base class(es). That reference is created when the class is created, not looked up by name later on when `super` gets called. Thus, the "incorrect" behavior that you're seeing is actually the expected behavior. To change what class `b` sees as its base class, you need to redefine `b` too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is happening because class b is still inheriting from the original class a that you defined.
You can check this by printing out the ids of the a classes

```
id(a)
id(b.__bases__[0])
```